# How to reset the icon associated to a given file type?

Tags: macos, icons, finder, file-association

An application I used (MacCaml) changed the icon of all files with `.ml` or `.oml` extension. I would want them to recover their original icon (a blank document). Here is what I have tried (with each time : Finder relaunching, rebooting, creating a new `.ml` file and opening it with different applications to see if its icon would change) :

- Setting “Always open with another application” (such as TextEdit).
- Going into the application bundle, removing the corresponding `.icns` file which gives the unwanted icon to all `.ml` files, replacing it by another `.icns` file.
- Deleting the application.
- Resetting Finder preferences.
- Trying to change the icon of one of these files (the usual way using Information window).
- Deleting all `.DS_Store` files.

Nothing worked. Have you got any suggestion ?
I think a possible solution would be also to know the answer to the following question :

**How to find where the icon associated to a given file is stored ?**

For I removed that unwanted `.icns` file from my computer, though there visibly exists one remaining copy of it which is being used by the Operating System. But using `find` and `fdupes` I wasn't able to find any duplicate of that file…

Answer (score 2):

I eventually solved the problem by rebuilding OS X’s LaunchServices database. A way to achieve this is the following command :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

(It is also possible to use [OnyX](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) utility.) A reboot has been necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have never actually tried this to remove an association, only ever add or change one, but the single go-to utility for Mac file associations has always been [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) (freeware).
First released in 2004 & hasn't been updated since 2009... but still works on Mojave.

It installs as a control panel.

1. Select the extensions tab [it may take some time to load up]
2. Scroll to your desired extension.
3. Change the Default App - this includes Default, Disable or Other...[which gives a file picker] as well as any app that has declared it can handle that file type.

I'm guessing Disable may remove all associations & revert the icon - it may need a reboot, or potentially a file.

Extension picked at random, I don't have the ones your question refers to.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is partially solved. The concerned file icons changed but :
— the unwanted icons briefly appears when the Finder window is loading
— one of the two icons displayed when opening the file in Xcode is the unwanted icon : https://i.imgur.com/SU3SJ7y.png
— all files displayed on Desktop have the unwanted icon if, and only if the icon size is set to <= 48 px ;
which is a very strange behaviour… Have you got any idea ?